# Why the messages of a control are not intercepted by the owner class?

Tags: mfc

I'm trying to code a simple grid view class based on the CListView class. In order to accomplish this task I created one class (CGridView) based on the ClistView class and one class (CGridEdit) based on the CEdit class. I would like to intercept EN_KILLFOCUS messages of CGridEdit in CGridView, but they never get there. This is the code:

```
// CGridView::OnInitialUpdate()
CRect rect; 
EditField = new CGridEdit(m_hWnd);
EditField->Create(WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_CENTER, rect, this, 0);


// Message Map entry
ON_MESSAGE(EN_KILLFOCUS,&OnEditFieldLostFocus)


// actual function
afx_msg LRESULT CGridView::OnEditFieldLostFocus(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(lParam == (LPARAM)EditField->m_hWnd)
    {
        // this never executes
        ...
    }
}
```

So the as the title says, why is this not working? I get some messages from CListView controls but the one from CEdit never gets there.. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

`EN_KILLFOCUS` isn't a message, it's a notification received via the `WM_COMMAND` message. You need to use [`ON_CONTROL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hkb8hew.aspx) in your message map.

Comment: Ah that's right, thank you. But the problem is that I would like to avoid using any user-defined IDs or messages. I don't want to define a fixed value, because there is always a conflict possibility in case if somebody was reusing my classes and had defined his own constants as well. It's not gonna happen, but I'd like to keep it proper. Do you know if there is any way to accomplish it without using defines, or at least any way to force a potential class user to define his own?